# Biden is both "proud dad & pop"?

Tags: colloquialisms

I searched for [Biden's twitter page](https://twitter.com/POTUS) and in his bio it states this: "46th President of the United States, husband to @FLOTUS, proud dad & pop."

Why would he say dad & pop? Isn't it the exact same thing?

Comment: It's not a well-stated question, with no real evidence of research, but the dialectal pop=grandfather isn't in many dictionaries, and this site is as concerned with Twitter as any place else.

Comment: https://mommypoppins.com/anywhere-kids/the-ultimate-list-of-cute-and-unique-grandparent-names.  Also, isn't this one for [ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Seems like this would be a good question for [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GEdgar is correct.

From an *Insider* article:

> Biden's grandchildren call him "Pop."

([Joe Biden's granddaughter Naomi is getting married at the White House. Meet his 6 grandchildren, whom he calls every day.](https://www.insider.com/joe-biden-kids-grandchildren-names-ages-2022-11),
Talia Lakritz, Nov 16, 2022, 5:20 AM)

Lakritz quotes the following [tweet from Naomi Biden](https://twitter.com/NaomiBiden/status/1511081396151984140), daughter to Joe Biden's son Hunter Biden:

> Peter and I are endlessly grateful to my Nana and Pop for the opportunity to celebrate our wedding at the White House

(12:40 PM · Apr 4, 2022
)

Another source: "[Who Are Joe Biden’s Grandchildren? Meet The Seven Kids Who Call The President ‘Pop](https://www.womenshealthmag.com/life/a39270628/joe-biden-grandchildren/)’" (Korin Miller, *Women's Health,* MAR 1, 2022)

Answer (score 12):

Maybe in some families the word "Pop" is used for grandfather...

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a more common usage in the US south (east of Texas). It's almost unheard of in the major northern urbs.

Comment: Pop or pop pop are usual in PA, https://www.coventrydirect.com/blog/popular-grandparent-names/

Comment: The Bidens are from Delaware, just south of Philadelphia.